# How to convert DeviceRGB to System.Drawing.Color?

Tags: colors, itext7, color-space, pdf-extraction

I am trying to get fill color of paths using itext7 using
fillclr= pathrenderinfo.getfillcolor.getcolorvalue()
but it gives the value in format of deviceRGB and I need to implement it in System.Drawing.Color. Is there any way to convert DeviceRGB color values to System.Drawing.Color ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in the following way:

```
float[] rgbValues = pathrenderinfo.GetFillColor().GetColorValue();
int redComponent = (int) rgbValues[0] * 255;
int greenComponent = (int) rgbValues[1] * 255;
int blueComponent = (int) rgbValues[2] * 255;
System.Drawing.Color color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(redComponent, greenComponent, blueComponent);
```